# Failed while sync the gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm working on Filter application where i have used third party lib for photofilter.But i'm getting this error while  syncing the `gradle`.

I have also tried link my app to link to `c/c++`.I have also added the `ndk` path and `android.mk` files too.

Gradle project`ndkBuild.path` is `D:\AndroidPhotoFilters-master\photofilterssdk\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk` but that file doesn't exist

Comment: Delete build folder file and rebuild your project.

Comment: From lib i have to delete?

Comment: Delete this folder files App->Build->intermediates

Comment: ok , i have deleted the intermediates.

Comment: Now,i have to rebuild the project?

Comment: I have deleted the build from project not from the libs.

Comment: i'm getting the same error

Comment: Paste full logcat please with build.gradle file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182014/discussion-between-shabnam-singh-and-syed-hamza-hassan).